# Sort 2-D list in R (mix of character and numeric)

Tags: r, sorting

I have a 2-D list with one column "names:chr" and the second column "n:int". This was created with the `count()` function in R. The "n:int" represent the occurrences of the names. Is there a way in R to sort or order the list base on the second column "n"? The list is a tibble.

Comment: Can you show `dput` of a small example.  If the columns are normal columns and not a list column, then `library(dplyr);df2 <- df1 %>% arrange(desc(n))`

Comment: `x[order(x$n),]` will order the frame `x` based on the value of `x$n`. (Though if you're using a `tibble`, you are likely also thinking `dplyr`, in which case @akrun's suggestion might be preferred, ala `arrange(x, n)`.)

Comment: Thje dput output is:     dput(list)                                                         structure(name = c("name1","name2",...), n = c(9L, 14L,....)),row.names = c(NA, -273L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Comment: Both arrange and the order commands worked. thank you